# How to convert an image string in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gzip, compression

I have this "little" problem...

In my web app, I receive an xml message from the server that I parse with jquery. In the xml there is an element `<Image>` with these attributes: **key** and **value**. The value attribute is a string that represents the image file (.png) compressed with the `gzip` algorithm (using the `System.IO.Compression` class in C#). Is there a way to decompress the **value** in javascript and then get the corresponding decompressed string?

Comment: Sorry, are you receiving an image content or path through a webservice?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it's a combination of already answered questions. You need to ungzip the string and then convert from string to image. When dealing with problems like this it's best to break it down into the smallest chunks you can. That way your searches will yield more applicable results if you can't find your exact issue.

[JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

[Javascript Hex String to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010408/javascript-hex-string-to-image)

Comment: Exactly as I thought people should break this down. Get the GZip out of the way and convert to image. Using DATA URI might have browser compatibility issue but not in near future.

Answer (score 1):

just simple example

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

where iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA... - is your value..

Answer (score 0):

I asume the image is base64 encoded. In that case you need to set the `src` property of the image with the image data prefixed with `data:image/png;base64,`

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: Just Firefox support this method.

Comment: Is this due to the gzip encoding, as I believe this worked in the latest version of Chrome. I would need to double check.

Comment: gzip compression does work and most common browsers (listed on w3c) are able to encode and decode to gzip so should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The server send to me the string of the image in a gzip compress format. I try the  tag but the browser seems not to decompress the image string. The image is converted in base64 format. Now I try again. Is there a way to check if the string is compress ed in the right way?