# Download image, then save locally and access: Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension which acts as the new tab page for a user. A number of users have asked for the ability to use their own, locally saved pictures as a background image. However, I have not been able to find a way to do this.
I am aware that there are many questions on StackOverflow with the same title as mine, but none address my specific needs:

- I need to download an image from a URL (i.e. a temporary Dropbox or Google Drive URL), or use an image from an HTML5 filepicker, as in [this](http://html5demos.com/file-api-simple) demo.
- The image then needs to be saved locally, preferably to the extension directory, and be accessed by the extension every time it loads
- I do not have access to PHP or to a server on which I could call a script or host images

The other answers suggest I use the Chrome FileSystem API. However, I understand that this API is only available to Chrome apps or on Chrome OS, not to extensions.
I also found an answer that mentions the file permission in the extension's manifest file.
`"permissions": [
    "file://*/*"
]`
I would not be against using such a permission, even though "The user has to manually approve this permission by visiting chrome://extensions/ and put a tick at the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox," as stated [on this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493020/adding-file-permission-to-chrome-extension).
However, I would not know where to start with implementing this. Your help is very much appreciated!

** I am using jQuery in my extension, so that is an option, although I would prefer to use pure JS.
*** The extension is [CleanStart for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cleanstart-for-chrome-a-n/gnkaijpoaggdacgdeajkblgkekhgjgga), in case that is important.

**Just an idea:**
Maybe I could use chrome.storage to save a hex string representing the image, and then retrieve that string and convert it back to an image, as in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010408/javascript-hex-string-to-image).

Comment: Is extension available at github?

Comment: Simply store the image as data URI in chrome.storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm How would I convert the image to a data URI? Is there a js/jQuery function?

Comment: It depends on how you read it. There are lots of examples you can find in several seconds on google.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Problem solved. Is there any way to close a question?

Comment: Well, you may add your own answer describing how you solved it which could be helpful to other people.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll do so as soon as I have solved the problem to my satisfaction!